# React : state has different value depending on where you ask

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of buttons that change a state, a string (used to decide if a modal is displayed ans as the title for this modal).
What should happen :

- 1. if the modal is not displayed, clicking on any of these buttons should change open the modal and set its title.
- 2. if the modal is displayed and the same button that opened it is clicked again, the modal should close (title cleared).
- 3. if the modal is displayed and another button is clicked, the modal should stay but its title should change (title changed).

Points 1 and 3 work fine. But 2 is not. So I decided to put some console.logs in there. If I log inside a useEffect linked to my state : title state changes on each button click that should change it but it's never cleared.

So I logged inside the handler function (triggered when a button is clicked) :

- title state always appears as an empty string, even if there's a title inside the modal.

So there it is, it doesn't make any sense to me.
Here's parts of my code if it helps :

```js
  const [logsModalTitle, setLogsModalTitle] = useState("");
...
  const handlingLogs = (inputClause) => {
    console.log("handling logs : ", showLogsModal, logsModalTitle);
    if (`${inputClause.name}(${inputClause.label})` === logsModalTitle) {
      setLogsModalTitle("");
    } else {
      setLogsModalTitle(`${inputClause.name}(${inputClause.label})`);
    }
  };
...
  <MyCustomButton
                buttonInnerText="ERROR"
                buttonSize="medium"
                buttonActionFunctionOne={handlingLogs}
                buttonActionPropOne={input.clauses[i]}
              />
...
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(logsModalTitle);
  }, [logsModalTitle]);
```

Any idea on what is causing this problem ?

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Full component is quite complex and linked to a lot of other things in my app or from different APIs so it's a bit of work to create a minimal reproducible example. Since my buttons and modal here are not directly linked to anything else for now, I just want to check if anyone has a solution before creating a MRE.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? I only see one `console.log` in your example. The question isn't clear.

Comment: There you go, I added the other console.log described in my question.

Comment: That's not making it any clearer. What is output at these logs? What did you expect? how is that relate to point 2: `if the modal is displayed and the same button that opened it is clicked again, the modal should close (title cleared).`

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion it is really strange code, but this may work:

```
const handlingLogs = (inputClause) => {
  if (`${inputClause.name}(${inputClause.label})` === logsModalTitle) {
    setLogsModalTitle("");
    setShowLogsModal(false);
  } else {
    setShowLogsModal(true);
    setLogsModalTitle(`${inputClause.name}(${inputClause.label})`);
  }
};
```

and you can use just one state as `showLogsModal = logsModalTitle !== "";`

```
const [logsModalTitle, setLogsModalTitle] = useState("");

const handlingLogs = (inputClause) => {
  if (`${inputClause.name}(${inputClause.label})` === logsModalTitle) {
    setLogsModalTitle("");
  } else {
    setLogsModalTitle(`${inputClause.name}(${inputClause.label})`);
  }
};

const showLogsModal = logsModalTitle !== "";
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I realized, when typing my question, that the boolean state is not useful indeed so I removed it altogether (edited my question). But the problem remains the same.

Comment: ok, i don't get what you want to achieve. it should work like that. also, if you display a "modal" it shouldn't be possible to click the buttons below anyway, or you mean just a popover?

Comment: and i can't see a modal in your question code.